# How to build own firmware for tp-link?

Tags: build, router, toolchain, firmware

A want to edit and build own firmware for tp-link wr841n.
I took source gpl firwmare with toolchain from official site. build it and get sepparated u-boot, kernel and filesystem.
how i can concatenate it in one file and flash to my routed?
is someone do that? thanks

Answer (score 3):

Full detailed answer to your question is pretty large.

The steps that you can follow are, sort of, like this:
Use ***binwalk***, ***firmware mod kit*** and ***dd***.
Usually, you need to know the offsets of firmware header,loader, kernel, filesystem, etc., on the original firmware file... 
use ***binwalk*** on the original bin firmware. 
You can extract the filesystem (usually, an *squashfs*) with **dd**, using the proper offsets,
and then, '*unsquash it*' with the proper tool on ***firmware mod kit***.
Make your modifications on the filesystem and then squash it again.
Now, with **dd**, you can put your new filesystem in the proper site on your firmware file, using the proper offsets. Take a look at this blog: http://www.devttys0.com

Comment: Hey, the links is down, is there anything news about it?